# unity Frustum Culling with drawmesh is culling too early

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm using

```
Graphics.DrawMesh(mesh, _matrix, material, 0, cam);
```

and my mesh is too height , so when move camera and when mesh inside in screen , it's not show early. it cullinged.
but when I new a Gameobject with MeshRenderer, it's no problem , it culling well, not too early. So what diffrence on here??

And I try to set mesh Bounds like this :

```
mesh.bounds = new Bounds()
            {
                center = Vector3.zero,
                extents = mesh.bounds.extents * 1000,
                max = mesh.bounds.max * 1000,
                min = mesh.bounds.min * 1000,
                size = mesh.bounds.size * 1000
            };
```

it's still not working .

Is also try this code: still not working...

```
void OnPreCull()
     {
         cam.cullingMatrix = Matrix4x4.Ortho(-99999, 99999, -99999, 99999, 0.001f, 99999) * 
                             Matrix4x4.Translate(Vector3.forward * -99999 / 2f) * 
                             cam.worldToCameraMatrix;
     }
 
     void OnDisable()
     {
         cam.ResetCullingMatrix();
     }
```

Comment: could you be getting caught up by some simple gotchyas .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36202761/294884  (notice the paragraph in ( ) brackets )

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to manually set the bounds of a mesh unless you have some crazy custom shader that drastically moves some vertices around.

If you're using a Unity Shader then you should be able to call `mesh.RecalculateBounds();` and have no problems

Comment: this might help (might be a unity bug?) https://forum.unity.com/threads/graphics-drawmeshinstanced-and-culling-the-how-and-why.633508/

Comment: Yes I also looked this thread , And I don't really understand how to fix that. it's mean chagne vertex positon?

Comment: some discussion .. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55418971/294884